# Change the function of a button if Logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am very new to the C#/ASP.NET-scene and I just can't seem to get the syntax right to do it myself. I want  a button's text and function
to change when the user is logged in. The code I have so far is:

> ```
> if (Session["Patient"] == "Logged In")
> {
>     Button3.Visible = false;
>     Button4.Visible = false;
> }
> else
> {
>     Button3.Text = "Create Account";
>     Button4.Text = "Log In";
> }
> ```

As far as I understand the code above changes the button's text,But how do I change the button's function?

Thanks in Advance:-)

Comment: You need to change the event handler - something like `Button3.OnClick -= <current event handler>; Button3.OnClick += <new event handler>;`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the same switch in the buttons event handler and call to different methods.

```
if (Session["Patient"] == "Logged In")
{
   LoggedInMethod();
}
else
{
   AnonymousMethod();
}
```

Comment: Haha I just woke up so I can;t use the bedtime-excuse :D.I thought so, Thank you for your help:-)